# onSaveInstanceState() isn't being called on my fragment

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

When I press the home button, the data in my fragment is being saved, but when I switch to another fragment, the method isn't even being called.

I even tried setting setRetainInstance() to be false, but it still isn't calling the function.

RedFragment.java

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;

import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class RedScorerFragment extends SherlockFragment {


    LayoutInflater infl;
    GridView mGrid;

    EditText[] etCollection;

    EditText mText;

    int R1C1, R1C2;
    String R1C3="";

    View tView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        infl = inflater;
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score_red, container, false);
        mGrid = (GridView) mView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewRed);


        setRetainInstance(false);//Do I need this?

        tView = container.getRootView();




        /*if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            //R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C1");
            R1C2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C2");
            R1C3 = savedInstanceState.getString("R1C3");

            //Log.d("savedd R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
            Log.d("savedd R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
            Log.d("savedd R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
        }
        */

        mGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            //R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C1", 0);
            R1C2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C2", 0);
            R1C3 = savedInstanceState.getString("R1C3");

            //Log.v("saved R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
            Log.v("saved R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
            Log.v("saved R1C3 ", R1C3);
        }
        else
            Log.w("instance state", "The instance state was null");

        //Log.v("saved R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
        //Log.v("saved R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
        //Log.v("saved R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C2", Integer.valueOf(etCollection[4].getText().toString()));

        Log.v("Saving", etCollection[0].getText().toString());


        savedInstanceState.putString("R1C3", etCollection[4].getText().toString());


    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context context;




        public ImageAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            etCollection  = new EditText[getCount()];
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View myView = convertView;
            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = infl;
                myView= li.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);


            }

            EditText editText = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red);
            etCollection[position] = editText;

            EditText oText = (EditText)tView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red);
            etCollection[0] = oText;
            return myView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 9;//only 9 
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            Log.w("etCollection: " + position , etCollection[position].getText().toString() );
            return etCollection[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;//mGrid.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I switch to another fragment, the method isn't even being called

That is because it is not supposed to be called then. It will be called when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called on the activity, which will be called in and around the `onPause()` and `onStop()` events.

Comment: So should I save the values in the `onPause()` event in the activity or the fragment?

Comment: @rasen58: I can't answer that. `onSaveInstanceState()` is only for transient data that should survive events like configuration changes.

Comment: @rasen58: Because it is not my data and not my app. All I can tell you is what the proper use and behavior of `onSaveInstanceState()` is.